# Benefit of rxjs subscription form value changes

Tags: angular

I have seen the following code elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
       <input [formControl]="control" />
       <div>{{ name$ | async | json }}</div>
   `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name$: Observable<string>;
  control;

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.control = this.builder.control('');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control.setValue('2');
this.name$ = this.control.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(this.control.value),
    map((name) => {
      console.log('fired', name)
      return name;
    })
  );
   
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. What's the benefit of using rxjs subscription to listen to form changes when the developer could have just put `(change)` methods directly on the form field instead?
2. I'm having trouble understanding as to what `pipe` and `startWith` are doing here?

Comment: if only want to "change" a value I don't see a benefit ( a bit or order?). But if you want to check the older value (you can use `pairwise`), control in an unique function the change of two or more controls (you can use `merge`), delay the execution (use `debounce` or `throttle`)... you use valuesChanges and pipe with this rxjs operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the benefit of using RxJs subscription to listen to form
> changes when the developer could have just put (change) methods
> directly on the form field instead?

The benefits of RxJs over the traditional `(change)` method are in the fact if you want to apply some additional transformations or RxJs utilities such as `skip`, `take` etc.

A few examples:

`distinctUntilChanged`: which only emits when the current value is different from the previous value.

`debounceTime` allows you to ignore events until a certain silent period is maintained between your events.

> I'm having trouble understanding what pipe and startWith are doing here?

`pipe` operator is used when you apply multiple RxJs operators on your Observable Stream. For example, I have an input where I want to have a 1-second delay between each stroke, and the input should be distinct. I would have to use the `pipe` operator to merge those different RxJs operators, Think of a pipe as an *assembly line* in a *factory* in which the *product*(Observable Stream) goes through and comes out as a *finished product*(value/response) in the end.

```js
 this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
         debounceTime(1000), 
         distinctUntilChanged()
         ).subscribe(value => {
             // Your code here
         });
```

`startWith` is an operator that tells your pipe operator to start the observable stream with this value. In your case being `this.control.value` which would be the initial value of your control

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are letting the async pipe to do all the work for you.
You have an observable stored in a variable:

```
name$: Observable<string>;
```

The async pipe is subscribing and unsubscribing when necessary to that observable and expects a string to be resolved and printed in the component template.

Since you have an observable you can use the .pipe() which will let you to do additional things with the observable every time a value is emitted. In this case you are setting a default value you could say, since you set the value of control to '2' and then using the pipe you are forcing the first value of the stream to be the '2' that you have set before.

Finally that map operator is not really doing nothing but printing a console.log

EDIT:
Every time a new value is emitted to the observer the pipe will be triggered, so for example with the map operator you could avoid the use of some certain strings like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var restrictedWords: string[] = ['word', 'bad'];
    this.control.setValue('2');
    this.name$ = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.control.value),
      map((value: string) => {
        if (restrictedWords.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          this.control.setValue('');
          return '';
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can see if you type some string included in the *restrictedWords* array then automatically the value will be set to an empty string.
This is just an example you can do whatever you want

Comment: Ah ok, so in this case the initial value is 2. If I then went in and typed 3 into the field I'd be presented with 23?

Comment: It will show whatever you put in the input box

Comment: I added more stuff to the answer. @AndrewJuniorHoward

Answer (score 0):

> What's the benefit of using rxjs subscription to listen to form
> changes when the developer could have just put (change) methods
> directly on the form field instead?

The benefit of using streams like the `name$` is that it allows you to add further operations (transform, filter, switch to another stream, etc.) in a reactive fashion. In addition, since it's already a stream, you can compose it with another stream to create a new stream.

Another way to do it as you mentioned is to react to each callback such as `(change)`, and it's quite a prevalent practice in some small cases and it doesn't have to be Observable, but if you have a lot of coordination, like for example on every change event you will request to the API debounced at 500ms, then you might consider a stream instead.

> I'm having trouble understanding as to what pipe and startWith are
> doing here?

`pipe` in rxjs allows you to chain operators whereas `startWith` operator set's an initial value to the Observable, this value will be the first to be emitted, an alternative to this is to create a BehaviorSubject and it will always guaranteed to fire at least one signal.